# Cakephp pagination for a custom function

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have a function in my model `EmployeePersonal.php` named `get_employee_details` which accepts some parameter and return the employees details. This function is used my many controllers and I prefer not to change this function.

Now I have a function `view` in my `EmployeePersonalsController.php` which outputs approx 4000 results. eg

```
$res = $this->EmployeePersonal->get_employee_details(
    $office_id = $office_id,
    $epf_no = $epf_no,
    $employee_personal_id  = $employee_personal_id,
    $status = $status,
    $permanent_district_id = $permanent_district_id,
    $present_district_id = $present_district_id,
    $department_id = $department_id,
    $designation_id = $designation_id,
    $category_id = $category_id,
    $gender_type = $gender_type,
    $offset = $offset,
    $size = $size
);
```

I need to put a pagination in my `view` function , is there any way how can I put the `$paginate` here ?

Comment: A method that takes 12 arguments, seriously? Also you should really get rid of these nonsense variable self assignments. That being said **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination**

Comment: It was written by previous ! I am modifying the project only :(

Comment: @Nitish And while you're modifying it, there's no shame in improving the code a little bit. This is also known as [the boy scout rule](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1235624&seqNum=6) and you'll be glad you did it if you ever return to this code at a later moment.